# CI/CD - Tagging jar artifact on release branch, Pipeline or Source code build?

Tags: java, git, maven, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Source code build is done using Maven. to generate java jar artifacts.

Development team says, source code(`develop` branch) build will only take responsibility to generate jar artifacts tagging SNAPSHOT, something like `x-y-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Development team is **not convinced** to change the source code(on `release` branch) build process to generate jar artifact `x-y-0.1-RELEASE.jar`.

As of now, Development team works on source code build that just create new commits in `develop` branch

For QA testing, we have started tagging the commits, so that QA pipeline can checkout specific tags to build/deploy/test in QA space.

---

So, current source code build on `develop` branch generate artifacts something like `x-y-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. We are yet to create `release` branch in Git.

---

Before Prod pipeline fetch code from `release` branch,

Does prod pipeline need to rename the artifact from `x-y-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `x-y-0.1-RELEASE.jar`?

or

Does source code build(in git source) on `release` branch need to be changed to generate `x-y-0.1-RELEASE.jar`?

For the above, please point me to standard references/recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot versions should not be renamed to release versions, they should be built as release versions. Everything that goes to production should be built as release version because you can run various checks during the build including that all dependencies are release versions as well.

A standard approach is to use the [Maven release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) which allows you to build a version like `1.2.3` from a git branch with `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`.